# cinnamon desktop broken after theme install

Tags: themes, cinnamon

I'm new to cinnamon. I installed a theme then uninstalled it from command line. But I have classic old looking gnome desktop, although I checked that I have cinnamon and reinstalled it just in case. But still, I have applications and places on left corner of my desktop.

And I cannot change to any theme for cinnamon from cinnamon settings.

Comment: If you have this: *applications and places*, you're **not** running Cinnamon, you're running Gnome Classic. What happens if you just remove the theme you installed?.

Comment: I uninstalled it before I reinstalled cinnamon. I logged out and logged in to cinnamon but still with no luck. Only cinnamon 2D works It makes sense as I id not make any changes to that. I still don't get why I can't run cinnamon.